# Firebase emulator (Firestore) times out on large dataset

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have exported my production data from Firestore which is roughly 2GB and I am trying to import it into the Firebase emulator. This causes a timeout error as follows: `Error: TIMEOUT: Port 4000 was not active within 30000ms`. Is there a way to increase this timeout?

I am reasonably sure that the cause of the issue is the size of the database as it works fine for a smaller dataset.

Furthermore, when I export a subset of the collections, documents for large collections don't show up in the emulator UI. The collection names show up but no documents. Again, there are no issues importing documents for smaller collections.

Are there any resources online that shed some light into how to handle large datasets or any documentation about the limitations of the Emulator? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your expectations on using the emulator. It is well [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite#what-is-emulator-suite) to not attempt to use these emulators as "self-hosted" versions of Firebase services. They are built for accuracy, not performance or security, and are not appropriate to use in production. I suggest creating a new test project for such purposes if that'll suit your needs.